# Task Assignment to agencies

Tags: task, variable-assignment

I have to automate task assignments for agencies which do a particular work. the automation should allow for assignment of tasks based on a group of search criteria.
1. There are more than one criteria that needs to be looked upon for while assigning tasks.
2. The algorithm should take in account the amount of requests in the queue and act accordingly. 
3. There should be fair assignment to the agencies

Comment: that's nice. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am planning to use a Task assignment algorithm, which caters to my criteria. I am working on the IBM Integration Designer, which allows me to configure the criteria in the form of a Decision Table. But, I am really clueless, what algorithm to use and how to go about it.

Comment: I'd suggest trying something, anything, then asking a question about how that specific implementation can be improved to meet your criteria. Otherwise you can't expect to get too  much out of so.